# Storing data offline until online is connected

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, local-storage

I am planning on making a Web app for feedback.  However the device it will be used on isn't connected online.

The idea is to have it store any input offline until it reaches a connection.  The device in question will be an ipad and the target database is mysql.

Ive seen Web storage but also wondering about offline site altogether as one could refresh the page by accident and with no connection it will fail.   Ideally I will use php,mysql and html5.  I was thinking originaly to store data I'm local storage then use ajax to keep pinging for a connection.  I'm looking for an elegant way of doing this without suffering any data loss.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for SO and more suited for a forum.

Comment: You cannot really do this at all just using a browser on an ipad, your only way to achieve that no data loss happens at all is to create an app for your ipad instead.   The user can close the browser or navigate to another page thus your ajax request will both be lost from memory and no longer attempting connection.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutly possible with a modern Browser.
You can use Service Workers to make the Page avalible offline, with it you can load and refresh the Site offline.
For Storage you can use Webstorage or IndexedDB like you already sayed.
And for detecting the Internet Connection, there are already Events provided by the Browser.

This concept is called Progressive Webapps, for an example you can look at the Google IO Page of this year

Comment: Many thanks for your response, this is exactly what I was looking for.  :)

Comment: Keep in mind that local storage and session storage have a very limited quota. IIRC it was something around 5MB you can expect from all browsers (per domain).

Comment: An iPad (Mobile Safari) should have an Limit at 50MB